# Creating for loop until list.length

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm reading about for loops right now, and I am curious if it's possible to do a for loop in Python like in Java.

Is it even possible to do something like

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
```

and can you do another for loop inside this for loop ?

Thanks

Comment: In Java, that loop is going to skip the first element of your list. Is that really what you want? If so, just use `my_list[1:]` instead of `my_list` in all of the answer below. If that was a mistake… well, that's exactly why Python doesn't do `for` loops the C/Java way, because it makes mistakes like this impossible.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In Python you can iterate over the `list` itself:

```
for item in my_list:
   #do something with item
```

or to use indices you can use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#xrange):

```
for i in xrange(1,len(my_list)):    #as indexes start at zero so you 
                                    #may have to use xrange(len(my_list))
    #do something here my_list[i]
```

There's another built-in function called [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#enumerate), which returns both item and index:

```
for index,item in enumerate(my_list):
    # do something here
```

examples:

```
In [117]: my_lis=list('foobar')

In [118]: my_lis
Out[118]: ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']

In [119]: for item in my_lis:
    print item
   .....:     
f
o
o
b
a
r

In [120]: for i in xrange(len(my_lis)):
    print my_lis[i]
   .....:     
f
o
o
b
a
r

In [122]: for index,item in enumerate(my_lis):
    print index,'-->',item
   .....:     
0 --> f
1 --> o
2 --> o
3 --> b
4 --> a
5 --> r
```

Comment: xrange() is no more available in Python 3. Instead the same can now be done using range(), however slightly differently than before.
for i in range(0,len(my_list)):

Comment: @vito There's no need to pass 0 to `range()`: `range(len(my_list))` works.

Comment: note: `xrange` is renamed to just `range` in python 3

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can, with [`range` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    # i is an integer, you can access the list element with l[i]
```

but if you are accessing the list elements anyway, it's more natural to iterate over them directly:

```
for element in l:
   # element refers to the element in the list, i.e. it is the same as l[i]
```

If you want to skip the the first element, you can [slice the list *<sup>[tutorial]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
for element in l[1:]:
    # ...
```

---

> can you do another for loop inside this for loop

Sure you can.

Comment: great, thanks for the help, i was looking for something like this and couldnt find anything...had to ask

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what do you need a loop for.

of course you can have a loop similar to Java:

```
for i in xrange(len(my_list)):
```

but I never actually used loops like this,

because usually you want to iterate

```
for obj in my_list
```

or if you need an index as well

```
for index, obj in enumerate(my_list)
```

or you want to produce another collection from a list

```
map(some_func, my_list)

[somefunc[x] for x in my_list]
```

also there are `itertools` module that covers most of iteration related cases

also please take a look at the builtins like `any`, `max`, `min`, `all`, `enumerate`

I would say - do not try to write Java-like code in python. There is always a pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could learn about Python loops here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Loops

You have to know that Python doesn't have { and } for start and end of loop, instead it depends on tab chars you enter in first of line, I mean line indents.

So you can do loop inside loop with double tab (indent)

An example of double loop is like this:

```
onetoten = range(1,11)
tentotwenty = range(10,21)
for count in onetoten:
    for count2 in tentotwenty
        print(count2)
```